# Icon resizing jTable column

Tags: java, swing, resize, icons, jtable

In my program it is possible to re-size the columns of a jTable. When the jTable is built the columns are automatically sized by length. But sometimes I want to change the size of a column because it is more readable when the table is printed on paper.

It is possible to show an icon like: [image: icon].

Now only the mouse is shown when re-sizing the columns

Does anyone if this is possible and how to do this?

Code of the table:

```
        private JTable table;
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setBounds(1, 1, 450, 0);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel_10.add(scrollPane);
    JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
    tableHeader.setResizingAllowed(true);
```

Maybe it is someting with my DefaultTableModel?

```
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM machinecodes WHERE type = '" + type +"'");

        while(rs2.next()){
       for(int i = 1; i < columns ; i++)
       {
            if(rs2.getString(1+i)==null) break;
            model.addColumn(rs2.getString(1+i));
       }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 1 ; i <= 25 ; i++)
                model.addColumn(i);

        }
        // Fetch each row from the result set
             while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] o = new Object[columns];
            // Get the data from the row using the column index
                for(int i = 0; i < columns ; i++)
            o[i]=rs.getString(i+1);

                            model.insertRow(0, o);
             }
```

Comment: please consider to cleanup the code formatting, it's near-to unreadable as is. (Note that this site's formatter doesn't play nicely with tabs .. but alas, we shouldn't be using tabs anyway in our code :)

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the JTableHeader and allow resizing:

```
JTable yourTable;
...
JTableHeader tableHeader = yourTable.getTableHeader();
tableHeader.setResizingAllowed(true);
```

Comment: my table is already re-sizable. But is it possible to show a icon when in the middle of two columns?

Comment: the resize mouse cursor should appear by default. May post your code, or better an SSCCE.

Comment: from the code posted nothing seems wrong. consider posting an SSCCE : http://sscce.org/ reproducing the problem.

Comment: true is the default value, no need to set it explicitly :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: right, I mistanderstood the question though. I think he's messing up something while modifying DefaultTableModel. Perhaps could be that don't firing fireTableStructureChanged can cause this problem?

Comment: I think the problem is because I use jTable table several times in my program with different amount of columns. Maybe thats the problem?